# Is taking surveys by random people supervised or unsupervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a list of cities like `London`, `Paris`, `Roma` etc.

I want to return which cities are interesting based on some features. I asked people to judge whether they find those cities interesting or not.  I show each city with the average of people's judgement of how interesting it is.

Is this supervised or unsupervised learning?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between supervised learning and unsupervised learning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832076/what-is-the-difference-between-supervised-learning-and-unsupervised-learning)

Comment: Sorry for that I didn't understand that explanation and I thought that my question style is correct.

Comment: Also I am very new in machine learning I couldn't explain what exactly in mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is supervised learning.
Supervised learning is when your training set consists of both the input data and the desired output data. In this case, the input data is the cities and the output data is the ratings that the people have given it.

What you are suggesting is a recommender system; these can be built using a technique called [collaborative filtering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering).